Confusion with Banach-Tarski argument
I'm getting confused with the argument from Donald Cohn's Measure Theory book's Appendix G. From my understanding he is saying that $n\in\mathbb{N}$ closed and disjoint balls (in $\mathbb{R}^3$) with equal radius can cover an arbitrary bounded set with non-empty interior. I don't see how this is true in general since to me the word "cover" would require the union of the balls containing the arbitrary set.
Here is a paraphrasing of the argument where I just shorten the less related parts of his proof:

Let $A,B\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ be bounded sets with non-empty interiors. Let $B_0$ be a closed ball included in $A$ and let its radius be denoted as $r$. Let $B_1,B_2,\dots$ be disjoint closed balls, each with radius $r$. (He now says $B_0$ is equidecomposable with $B_1\cup B_2\cup\dots\cup B_n$ for arbitrary $n$). $\textbf{Since $B$ is bounded, we can choose $n$ large enough that $B$ can be}$ $\textbf{covered with $n$ closed balls of}$ $\textbf{radius $r$}$. (He then says B is equidecomposable with a subset of A).


Hello, just a think : the closure of $B$ is compact so that you can cover it by a finite number of closed balls of radius $r$. Then it is also true for $B$ as it is included in its closure. I don't know if it was the problem.

By the way : "From my understanding he is saying that $n\in\mathbb{N}$ closed and disjoint balls (in $\mathbb{R}^3$) with equal radius can cover an arbitrary bounded set with non-empty interior.", no ! He's saying that for every such set, there exists a $n$ such that...

Is it true that a compact set can be covered by a finite number of closed balls of radius r? Also, they need to be disjoint since he wants $n$ s.t. $B$ is contained in $B_1\cup\dots\cup B_n$.

The defining feature of a compact set is that for any open cover you can select a finite subcover. So cover it with open balls and extract the finite subcover.

I have a feeling that there is some confusion regarding the the concept of "covering" versus the concept of "equidecomposable" in the formulation of this post: why are the parenthetical comments on equidecomposability intermixed with a discussion of coverings that, on the face of it, has nothing to do with equidecomposability?

I also have a feeling that there are hidden assumptions/conclusions in various statements; for instance why would you say in the comment that the balls need to be disjoint, which is not usually required for a covering?

So there should be more details in the post to explain these various issues more clearly.

Yes, there could be more information, but I also have to mindful of how much I write so that I don't push people away due to the length. I tried presenting my doubt (Is it true we can cover any bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with closed disjoint balls?) and I gave some context to my problem in case I was misunderstanding the statement.

Yes, a compact set can be covered by a finite number of closed balls.  The balls need not be disjoint for this argument.  We want to show that we can make an injective function from $B$ into $A$.  We find $n$ balls that cover $B$, so $B \subset B_1 \cup B_2 \cup \ldots B_n$. We use the Banach-Tarski theorem to find a bijection between $B_0$ and all the points in all the balls.  If the balls overlap the same point in space will have more than one representation, one for each ball that it is part of, but this is not a problem.  Now for each point in $B$ find a ball it is part of.  If there is more than one, pick any one.  Use the bijection to match it with a point in $B_0$.  Not all the points in $B_0$ are matched, but the ones that are form a subset of $A$ so we have injected $B$ into $A$.  You can then use the process in reverse to inject $A$ into $B$ and use Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein to infer there is a bijection between $A$ and $B$.

I understand your proof, but unfortunately this argument is part of Cohn's proof showing that the assumption "the closed unit ball is paradoxical w.r.t. the group of rigid motions" implies the Banach-Tarski paradox as you use it here. So this is certainly not what he had in mind.

I learned Banach-Tarski from Stan Wagon's book.  He proves you can make a correspondence between one ball and two explicitly, then (as I recall) uses the above argument to show you can go from any compact set with interior to any other.  I am surprised to see the section you cite coming before any explicit construction.

I understand, I might have a look at the book tomorrow. To give more context, Cohn wants to show that the Banach-Tarski paradox is equivalent to the paradoxicality of the closed unit ball because he proves the latter to show that the paradox is true.
From my understanding, he wants the balls to be disjoint because he uses the fact that equidecomposability is an equivalence relation, so $B_0$ is equidecomposable with $B_1\cup B_2$ and then with any finite union by iterationon. That's part of what I omitted.

Yes, once you get one ball to two you can go from one to any finite number so the one to two is the first step.  Then you use an argument like mine to say the balls don't have to be disjoint to get any compact set to any other.
